# How to show Toaster after logout

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have to show the toaster once I logout from the application. Here is what I am trying. Here I am calling toaster after my logout method.

```js
_this.logout().then({
  success: function (result, request) {
    Ext.toast({
      html: 'Logged Out',
      width: 270,
      cls: 'smart-window alert-box',
      bodyStyle: 'background:#90EE90;',
    });
  },
  failure: function (result, request) {
    console.log('failure!');
  },
});
```

I have another approach where I am calling toaster before the logout but it is getting disapper after logout. How I can show toaster after logout whih is re directing on toaster page.

Here is my `logout` where I am redirecting.

```
logout: function (options) {
        let deferred = Ext.create("Deft.promise.Deferred");
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/logout',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (result, request) {
                var url = '/myUrl/logout';
                var method = 'GET';
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: url,
                    method: method,
                    success: function (result, request) {
                        let extraParam = "someconfig";
                        let external_logout = "/someurl";
                        
                        window.location.href = `${external_logout}${extraParam}`, 'width=1000 height=1000, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes';
                        
                        deferred.resolve(logout);
                    },
                    failure: function (result, request) {
                        deferred.reject();
                    }
                });
            },
            failure: function (result, request) {
                Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', 'Request failed');
                deferred.reject();
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

`then` of promise object suppose to get only a **callback**.

```js
_this.logout().then(() => {
  Ext.toast({
    html: 'Logged Out',
    width: 270,
    cls: 'smart-window alert-box',
    bodyStyle: 'background:#90EE90;',
  });
});
```

Comment: This is fine but after logout it is redirecting to the login page and toaster is not coming.

Comment: Because of the fact that you are "hard" navigating the page, you don't have anything to do, cause you will "flush" the entire page.

Comment: You maybe can wait for the toast to disappear and only then navigate out.
Or use your "spa" router to navigate to the next page (this navigation won't flush the page)

Comment: Other option is to "flag" your next page to show the toast, usually done by adding some url query param

Comment: In second option I need to code in plain javascript file in my index html. In first option can you pleas share some more light on spa router.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220750/discussion-between-felixmosh-and-david).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make use of localStorage. Set isLoggedOut=true just before redirecting.

And in the new Page check :

```
if(isLoggedOut===true)
    show toaster for 5/10 seconds. then set it to false;
else 
    continue as usual.
```